# How to check the JSON data is coming empty from the PHP and display the message?

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am fetching the records from the database using AJAX and displaying the data on view page using JSON. Everything is working on it.

Now When I am getting empty JSON data then it will display the "No data found" from my PHP page and that is displaying in the `network tab`. but I am not able to check the empty data in my AJAX to display the message on my view page.

**Controller**

```
if (empty($result) || count($result)==0){
      echo "No data found";
         // return 0;
    }
 else 
    {
      foreach ($result as $row)
        {
        $arr_result[] = array(
              "name" => $row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname,
              "mobileno" => $row->mobileno,
              "email_id" => $row->email_id
            );
          }
          echo json_encode($arr_result);
        }
```

**Custom.js**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + "/Employee_control/search_addSalaryrecord",
        method: "POST",
        data: {employee_name: employee_name,crm_id:crm_id,employee_id:employee_id},
        success: function(response) {
        //alert(response);
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
          if (data.status == 'error')
             {
                 alert(data.msg);
             }
             else{
        $('.personel_info').show();
            var trHTML = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, o){
                  $('#name_emp').text(o.name);
                  $('#mobileno_emp').text(o.mobileno);
                  $('#employee_email').text(o.employee_email);
                 });

                      }     
        }             

   });
```

In the console, I am getting the error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More](I know my response is empty that the reason I am getting this error)
```

at the line of `var data = JSON.parse(response);`

I tried

```
    if (json.success) {
    alert('All working');
    }
    else{
    alert('no data');
    }
but still getting the same issue.
```

Comment: What does the `alert(response);` print out in your ajax success method when the response is empty? Does it print: "No data found"?

Comment: @Ivan86, No I am not getting any output in the alert(response)